# Finding max value using Sumproduct

Tags: arrays, excel, date

I have around 10k data pairs date-value and for calculation of averages for various time periods (using x values for the specific dates for the y number of years) i need to find the max value of the year as the fresh data are coming in (for example - the last 5 years could cover the range of 2015-2019 and 2014-2018).

I tried to use:

```html
{=SUMPRODUCT(--(DAY(A2)=DAY(T!$A$3:$A$10000));--(MONTH(A2)=MONTH(T!$A$3:$A$10000));MAX(YEAR(T!A3:A10000)))}
```

but it returns #VALUE! In the same time - {MAX(YEAR(T!A3:A10000)))} returns expected max value of the year in the data array.

Actually, I need some solution to find the max value of the year in the data set  having the same DD & MM, the rest would be easy.

Janis

Comment: just curious.. why not just max() the sumproduct() , with the year() inside it.. ?

Comment: It is not the problem to find the max year, the problem is to find the max year for the specific date, for exapmle - for the record of 01.01.2019 max(year) will be 2019, but if the last value for the 02.01. will be 2018, max(year) shall be 2018 (all data in the same list). =SUMPRODUCT(--(DAY(A7)=DAY(T!$A$3:$A$10000));--(MONTH(A7)=MONTH(T!$A$3:$A$10000));YEAR(T!$A$3:$A$10000)) give the sum of the year values (2018+2017+...etc)

Comment: I'm not good with array formula.. but if I were to suggest.. put a `=IF(AND(MONTH(A3)=MONTH($A$2),DAY(A3)=DAY($A$2)),YEAR(A3),"")` at A4 then drag downwards.. then find the max from this range should work. Good luck. ( :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

current workaround:

```html
=YEAR(T!A3)-1+SUMPRODUCT(--(DAY(A2)=DAY(T!$A$3:$A$10000));--(MONTH(A2)=MONTH(T!$A$3:$A$10000)))
```

where the cell T!A3 contains the known first and min value of the year(). It works, but I do not like it as it binds evrth to the specific cell.